# How is the libs path "/run/opengl-driver" injected into Nix binaries like compton

Tags: linux, opengl, nix, nixos

First I am not really comfortable with ELF and all this library linking process. But after having played a bit with Nix/NixOS, there is something I still don't really understand with the way graphic drivers are linked into binaries.

One of the designs of Nix/NixOS is that the OpenGL driver cannot be part of the reproducible environment because it will depend on the target hardware.

Most Nix programs find OpenGL drivers into "/run/opengl-driver/lib".

In the case of a NixOS system, drivers are downloaded and installed at this path and then the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can be defined globally in the configuration using `hardware.opengl.setLdLibraryPath = true` (see https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/hardware/opengl.nix#L166).

However, in the case of a non-NixOS operating system, I can notice that programs still reference this `/run/opengl-driver/lib` path while `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not defined anywhere. And so my question is: **why does a binary still search drivers into /run/opengl-driver/lib on a non-NixOS system?**

My example here is compton. Its derivation in Nixpkgs is at the following address.

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/274e095f761b2da76a376d105c41591739350b14/pkgs/applications/window-managers/compton/default.nix#L51

I can see using strace that the program tries to load the `libGLX_mesa.so` library at runtime.

```
$ strace -e openat $(readlink -f $(which compton)) 2>&1 | grep -E ".*opengl.*.so"

openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/tls/haswell/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/tls/x86_64/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/tls/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/haswell/x86_64/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/haswell/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/x86_64/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/opengl-driver/lib/libGLX_mesa.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Indeed, using `ldd` reveals that `libGLX_mesa.so` is not dynamically linked.

```
$ ldd $(readlink -f $(which compton)) | grep mesa | wc -l
0
```

So my guess is that this library is loaded at runtime maybe using `dlopen`. I cannot find any reference of `dlopen` in https://github.com/chjj/compton but maybe it is done indirectly from one of the libs linked by compton.

If my guess is true, I have found that `dlopen` was able to find the desired library searching into paths defined in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (when the path is a leaf name).

So my next move was to analyse the environment variables available to compton at runtime using one of the two commands below.

```
$ strace -v -s 10000 -e execve $(readlink -f $(which compton)) 2>&1 | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH | wc -l
0

$ ltrace -e getenv $(readlink -f $(which compton)) 2>&1 | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH | wc -l
0
```

But this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not seem to be defined. And I am kind of stuck in my analysis here.

So to recap, my questions are:

- How is this opengl path `/run/opengl-driver/lib` injected into compton?
- What would be the standard way of adding this library path to programs requiring graphic drivers in Nix?
- And last question not really related to this analysis but: if wanting to make compton work on a non-NixOS system, would it be enough to manually link opengl libraries from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to `/run/opengl-drivers/lib/`?